# Error occurs when adding foreign key from ASP.Net MVC 5 Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Customer Model :

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And I this is what my IdentityModel.cs looks like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    //new
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

After writing that code, I ran ***enable-migrations***, ***add-migrations*** and then ***update-database*** without any errors occurring.

When I tried to create a *MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework*, using the model Customer with a new data context class, I got this error :

[image]

Whats going wrong? I haven't changed anything other than the ApplicationUser : IdentityUser class and Customer class.

**I'm very new** to this so I would appreciate extremely detailed instructions :)

Comment: Can you show context class code? Probably you need to add something like `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` there.

Comment: I assume u meant the ApplicationDbContext class? I haven't done anything to it. But I added it anyway. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Yep, I want at least to see your `ApplicationDbContext` & other related context class first. There was something that configured wrong since it missed PK definition of Identity tables.

Comment: I added it to the Identity Model.cs. Just refresh. I only changed the ApplicationUser class. Others i didnt change. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: At this time, try to add `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` inside overridden `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method. Let me know if this solved the problem.

Comment: I added that and updated the post. Still getting the same error. Is the code right? I didnt update the database btw. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146827/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-ryan-vancity-gosling).

Answer (score 0):

Altough you didn't post the IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, etc. I can imagine you didn't define primary keys for these classes. Entity Framework requires each and [every entity to have a key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx).
You can either follow the convention and name your primary key properties *Id* or *ClassNameId* or use data annotations, the Key in particular.

## UPDATE

The underlying problem is not related to the foreign key, but to the lack of a primary key.

First, you shouldn't define a property as both Key and ForeignKey.
Remove the Key attribute from the UserId and leave just the ForeignKey.
Next define an Id property like so:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework is intelligent enough to identify it as the Primary Key.
Do this in all your entities, update the database and you're good to go.

Comment: How would I go around doing that? Im still unfamiliar with MVC and ASP.net